# After sleep state, PC with Linux doesn't let me shut down the system

Tags: linux, networking, sleep, shutdown

I have been using Xubuntu as my main system for 3 weeks, but I noticed only today that after the pc has woken up from the Sleep state it doesn't let me shut down the system.
I tried to shut down by using `sudo shutdown now` but what I get is

> Failed to execute operation: There's already a shutdown or sleep operation in progress

There is another problem, as well, when the PC wakes form sleep it can't connect to the Network, I only use Ethernet connection, but it tells me that there is no connection available.
My PC works flawlessly until it goes in sleep state, I can't figure out what is causing my machine not to work when it wakes from sleep state.

Comment: might be better asked on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by changing my Nvidia drivers, it seems those proprietary drivers were causing the problem.